# How to determine whether an index of an array of unknown type is empty?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, null

```
template<typename K, typename V, int N>
    class KVList
    {
        int m_size;
        K m_key[N] = {};
        V m_value[N] = {};

    public:
        KVList& add(const K&, const V&)
        {
             //Check if index is empty or null
                    //Add key value pair
        }
    }
```

Hey guys,

I'm creating a templated class that has 3 template parameters. My question, as stated above, is how I can determine whether or not an array at certain indexes is NULL or has no user-defined value.

Currently passing these datatypes as template arguments:

```
w4::KVList<std::string, double, 5> x;
w4::KVList<std::string, std::string, 5> y;
```

I was thinking maybe something along the lines of type conversions to bool might help but I'm stuck.

How can I check if the index has a null value for occurrences `KVList` accepts different datatypes or classes than the ones specified above?

Comment: Array elements are *never* "empty". They will always have a value. And you initialize your arrays, so depending on the types, they will have default-constructed object or zero-initialized values.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null" or "empty" double or int.

Comment: Why are you asking about array when you clearly have Key and Value pairs?

Comment: _@Schwiftyy_ Can you elaborate at what you actually want to solve with that code? There might be alternatives you might not have thought of. E.g. `std::optional` might come in handy.

Comment: @TheDude It's supposed to be a parallel array that uses N to declare size of the array and I guess iterate through it. K and V to be used like a dictionary. Let me rephrase it better, I want to know whether or not the array index is not user-defined so I can add values at the index.

Comment: @Schwiftyy Sorry. Not really clear for me yet. What's your real world problem to solve? (Besides trying to deduce information from template parameters which isn't available with your model.)

Comment: @TheDude It's for an assignment but it's exactly that; used to manage lists of key value pairs. Having the console, for example, accept a Product(Key) and then a Price(Value) that can relate to that Product for Inventory. Another would be like a glossary to have a Word(Key) and then the Definition(Value). I can implement by using std::string::empty() to check but I want it to be flexible enough to handle other datatypes.

Comment: How it will be used: https://puu.sh/zlznN/13173b9a5d.png

Comment: @Schwiftyy There's no _empty_ or _null_ value for primitive (intrinsic) data types like `int` or `double` in c++. You may represent such using a `std::optional` as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know whether or not the array index is not user-defined so I can add values at the index.

You could add a third C-style array of `bool`'s

```
bool isSet[N] = {};
```

and set/unset the values when keys and values are set/unset.